# Django - Saving object worked one time but now it doesnt

Tags: django

i want to save an object to db and it worked one time but now it doesnt, i suspect that is something to do with the Glossary

Everything

views.py

```
@login_required
def product_form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Product_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            product_form = form.save()
            product_form.save()
            return redirect('product_management_view')
    else:
        form = Product_Form()
    return render(request, 'product-form.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Product (models.Model):

    sub_chapter = models.ForeignKey(Sub_Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    glossary = models.ManyToManyField(Glossary, blank=True )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    product_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='media/images/product_images', blank=False, null=False)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    length = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=15, decimal_places=4, null=True)
    polution = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=8, max_digits=15, null=True, blank=True )
    technical_implementation = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("manufacter_product_view", kwargs={'id': self.pk})
```

forms.py

```
class Product_Form(forms.ModelForm):




    sub_chapter  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sub_Chapter.objects.all(), 
        required=True, widget=forms.Select())



    supplier  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Supplier.objects.all(), 
        required=True, widget=forms.Select())




    glossary  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Glossary.objects.all(), 
        required=False, widget=forms.SelectMultiple())



    product_image = forms.ImageField(
        required=True, widget=forms.FileInput())




    class Meta():
        model = Product
```

fields =[ 'name', 'description', 'reference', 'width', 'height', 'length', 'polution', 'unit_price', 'technical_implementation', 'sub_chapter', 'supplier', 'glossary', 'product_image', ]

Comment: What error or response you are getting in subsequent request?

Comment: First of all let me thank you, it doesn t redirect, i thought that initially that form.is_valid returned false, but it did work one time, in the terminal i got this         [21/Oct/2019 17:40:25] "POST /product-management/product-form/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13587
Not Found: /product-management/product-form/...

Comment: when saved it didn t redirect

Comment: So you are saying that first time it got redirected to "product_management_view" but when you again filled the form after reloading the page it didn't redirected?

Comment: when it saved it remained in the form only worked one time, now it doesn t save and doesn t redirect

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your product_form_view, you are calling the save method on product_form variable i.e **product_form.save()** but product_form will have None in it as form.save() will return None on successfully saving the object,so it will break the code there.And you don't need to again call the save method at all.Calling **form.save()** is enough for saving the object and you should move the code in else part out of it as it not currently handling the form invalid case. 
Your code should be like this:

```
@login_required 
def product_form_view(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = Product_Form(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('product_management_view') 
    form = Product_Form() 
    return render(request, 'product-form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: i know its not the cleanest way, but it works i have other views that work fine, if you had commit=True, i tried many ways and the code that i posted here was that , i tried your code and it didn t work, i pretty sure is something to do with the ManyToManyField, thank you for your help